# How to create a symbol from a tikz figure in ConTeXt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, context

I have succesfully drawn a symbol (number in a pentagon) using a TikZ figure with the following code:

```
this is a very very very very very very very very very long text before symbol%
\starttikzpicture
% draw pentagon
\draw  (90:0.2)  node{}-- (162:0.2) node{}-- (234:0.2) node{}-- (306:0.2) node{}-- (378:0.2) node{}-- cycle;
% draw text inside pentagon
\draw  (0,0) node{10};
\stoptikzpicture%
text after symbol
```

It kind of works but the figure/symbol is not well aligned vertically, and causes a huge line spacing just above itself, as shown below:

[image]

How could I solve this? Is there a better option than TikZ to create such a  symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `baseline` key to vertically align your Ti*k*Z symbol:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
this is a very very very very very very very very very long text before symbol%
this is a very very very very very very very very very long text before symbol%
\starttikzpicture[baseline=-3pt]
% draw pentagon
\draw  (90:0.2)  node{}-- (162:0.2) node{}-- (234:0.2) node{}-- (306:0.2) node{}-- (378:0.2) node{}-- cycle;
% draw text inside pentagon
\draw  (0,0) node{10};
\stoptikzpicture%
text after symbol
\stoptext
```

[image]

By default Ti*k*Z places the lower end of your picture on the baseline. If you remove all your nodes from the pentagon and remove the padding from the node holding the 10, you get good results without manually aligning it with the `baseline` key:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
this is a very very very very very very very very very long text before symbol%
this is a very very very very very very very very very long text before symbol%
\starttikzpicture
% draw pentagon
\draw  (90:0.2)  -- (162:0.2) -- (234:0.2) -- (306:0.2) -- (378:0.2) -- cycle;
% draw text inside pentagon
\draw  (0,0) node[inner sep=0pt]{10};
\stoptikzpicture%
text after symbol
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works perfectly as far as the baseline alignment is concerned: removing nodes from pentagon and padding from text node indeed places the figure correctly. However, I still have an increased line spacing (as in the picture from my original post). If I only keep the text node, the line spacing is OK. If I replace the pentagon by a circle of same diameter, the line spacing is not OK. Any idea where this could come from?

Comment: @Silverspur Because your object is bigger than the baseline skip allows. Reduce its size. If it visually isn't too big, it might be because of some control points of Ti*k*Z. You can use the `\useasboundingbox` path to set a bounding box explicitly (e.g. `\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (1,1);` would create a bounding box of 1cm times 1cm and everything outside that box isn't considered for the placement of TeX).

Comment: Reducing the object size worked for me. As a side note, the `useasboundingbox` command, however, seems to only work to define a *larger* bounding box than automatically computed by TikZ.

Comment: @Silverspur then you're most likely misusing the `\useasboundingbox` path, it can reduce the size. If you for instance use `\useasboundingbox;` your picture will have zero size and overlap with the following symbol.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of TikZ you could also use MetaFun which integrates really well into ConTeXt and is orders of magnitudes faster than TikZ.

```
\startuniqueMPgraphic{pentagon}
R := 2 / (1 + sqrt(5)) * max(OverlayWidth, OverlayHeight) ;
draw (0, R) for i = 1 upto 4:
    -- (R * cosd(90 + i*72), R * sind(90 + i*72))
endfor -- cycle ;
setbounds currentpicture to fullsquare xyscaled(OverlayWidth, OverlayHeight) ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
    [pentagon]
    [\uniqueMPgraphic{pentagon}]

\defineframed
    [pentagonframed]
    [background=pentagon,
     frame=off,
     location=low]

\starttext

\samplefile{lorem}%
\pentagonframed{10}
\samplefile{lorem}%

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: It will be nice if you could also show the usage with `\defineframed`, so that one does not always need to type `\inframed[background=pentagon, frame=off]{...}`.

Comment: @Aditya Done...